# Spark stateSnapshots() not working with saveAsHadoopFiles

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

In my Spark Streaming 1.6 application, I want to store certain value in `mapWithState` and then periodically save them to disk as a backup option.

```
JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, SwMessage, CcState, Tuple2<String, CcState>> SwMessageWithState = 
  pairSwMsg.
    mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc).
    initialState(cStateMap));
```

For backing up I am using the `stateSnapshots()` method as follows.

```
SwMessageWithState.stateSnapshots().
  saveAsHadoopFiles("/ccd/snap", "txt",String.class,CcState.class, TextOutputFormat.class);
```

The problem I am facing is that the program stops consuming the messages after the first batch and then does nothing.

If I comment the `stateSnapshots()` line the program works fine.

Can somebody suggest what exactly is wrong with the above statement?

Also I was thinking of making the snapshopt directory as an `initialState` state file next time the `SparkStreaming` job runs.